# First order per customer

Tags: powerbi, dax

Given the following data model:

[image]

I need to build a report that will display the following attributes:

[image]

As you see, I need to provide an attribute from the `SalesOrder` table [InternDocumentNumber[, so the visual will have grain on the order level.

Now, the problem is with measure [first order date v1] that should calculate the first order date made by the customer and display this value for all different orders from the same customer.

So far, I build the following measure

```
first order date v1 = CALCULATE (
FIRSTDATE( SalesOrderDate[SalesOrderDate]),
USERELATIONSHIP( SalesOrder[OrderDate], SalesOrderDate[SalesOrderDate]),
CROSSFILTER ( SalesOrder[OrderDate], SalesOrderDate[SalesOrderDate],both ),
ALL(SalesOrder)
)
```

However, this measure calculates forever, ending with the error:

[image]

Could you please advise me on how to write this measure, so it will perform better?

**EDIT**

Let me use an example from  DAX.DO to be more clear on what I would like to get. Below is a screen of query and the result

[image]

What I would like to achieve is a measure, that will show me the min date for order on a customer level, and not the order level, as it is now. In other words, values in the red rectangle should be the same for customer 6, regardless of the grain of the table. Is this possible in DAX at all?

Reference to DAX.DO snippet:

https://dax.do/wxU6NNRHrencrg/

**EDIT 2**

Actually, I am able now to design a measure that solves the problem, however it performs very bad (timeouts in the end)

Here is the code screen and the DAX.DO reference

[image]

https://dax.do/wxU6NNRHrencrg/

Comment: What is the difference between SalesOrderDate[SalesOrderDate] and SalesOrder[OrderDate] ?

Comment: @AntrikshSharma I have edited the post. Hope it will be more clear if I refer to open dataset Contoso rather then my particular data model.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( Sales[Order Date] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Sales, Customer[CustomerKey] )
)
```